# Launch runnable run from native java application

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, nativeapplication

I currently have the following problem:

I have two java applications: **updater** and **client**. The updater is a native application (which contains the necessary JDK), while the client is just a runnable jar file.

When the user starts the application, it basically starts the updater, which searches for an update for the client application on the server. When a new update is present, the updater downloads the update and places it in a file (or overwrites the current jar file). Then, I execute the downloaded .jar file like this:

```
private void startApplication() {

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process pr = rt.exec("java -jar libs/myJar.jar");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This works fine when building and running in Eclipse, but when I run the native application (which is built by Eclipse) myJar.jar doesn't get executed. I think it is due to the fact that the updater can not find the jar file, because it absolute path becomes different.

**My question:** How can I make sure that the native application can execute the downloaded jar file?

Note: I am currently building the app on Mac OSX, so I am testing this with a .dmg. I don't know if the problem is also present for Windows or Linux.

**Edit 1:** It doesn't seem to be a problem with the path, because this seems to be fine (as tested with  @Funtik, thank you for that).

**Edit 2:** The file permissions also seem to be correct. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that the client jar doesn't know which JVM to use?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use absolute path for this.

```
 String path = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
 Process pr = rt.exec("java -jar "+ path + "/libs/myJar.jar");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just tried it, but it doesn't seem to work. It does work while running it from the IDE, but not when I compile the native application and run it.

Comment: try to output the path to console and see where you're actually located

Comment: This is the path: /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Java/. , which seems to be okay.

Comment: so the full path to the client.jar is the following?  /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Java/libs/myJar.jar?

Comment: Yes, that it correct. When I run the jar from inside the package, everything seems to work fine. So maybe there is something wrong with the package.

Comment: check the file permissions inside .dmg if the java is allowed to read the jar file

Comment: The file permissions are all correct (read/write). Maybe it has something to do with the fact that the downloaded client jar does not know which JVM to use?

Comment: Are you able to launch the client, but it fails in runtime?

Comment: Yes, I can launch it manually from within the folder, but the runtime fails.

Comment: please post the full stacktrace

Comment: Where can I find the stacktrace when I run a native application? I am not able to find the Java console anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm lost here. You are launching the process from the java code. So this code gets executed in a java runtime, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Okay I finally found a way to view the java console, and it does not give a specific error. However, I printed the "path" string as you suggested it in your example, and it prints the home folder of my mac, which is obviously not right! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that means that the JVM is started in your home folder, not inside the .dmg file. I guess you have to know the absolute path to the dmg file, to get everything working